# Node's 'ECONNRESET' error occurring on http.ClientRequest in proxy app

Tags: node.js, http, econnreset

I've written a proxy app in node. It forwards a client request to an upstream server and forwards the upstream server's response back to the client.

Occasionally, the `http.ClientRequest` which is made to the upstream server will emit the error event with `{code: "ECONNRESET", errno: "ECONNRESET", syscall: "read"}`. There's nothing special about this specific request as it succeeds hundreds of times between periodic failures. Inspecting the logs of the upstream server (which happens to be Varnish), it seems that the request in question *is never received*.

Are there any pointers as to what the cause of this behaviour may be? Any specific approach I should take in debugging or somehow mitigating this?